# Como configurar a versão do java?

Tags: java, maven

Seguindo o passo a passo da aula 1.3 Introdução ao *Maven*, temos o seguinte código (substitua *colchetes* por *braquets*):

```
[modelVersion]4.0.0[/modelVersion]
  [groupId]com.algaworks[/groupId]
  [artifactId]comecando-primefaces[/artifactId]
  [version]0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[/version]
  [packaging]war[/packaging]

  [properties]
    [project.buid.sourceEncoding]UTF-8[/project.buid.sourceEncoding]
  [/properties]

  [build]
    [plugins]
        [plugin]
            [artifactId]maven-compiler-plugin[/artifactId]
            [version]3.1[/version]
            [configuration]
                [source]1.8[/source]
                [target]1.8[/target]
            [/configuration]
        [/plugin]
    [/plugins]
  [/build]

[/project]
```

A configuração da versão do java está em 1.8. Entretanto, a configuração oficial continua 1.5. Já usei `Maven->Update Project->Ok`, o que no vídeo deu certo, mas no meu eclipse não seu certo, continuou 1.5.

Além disso, o *Eclipse* aponta um erro na linha 6 (`[version]0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[/version]`). Forçar atualização do *maven* não resolveu o problema, ao contrário do que o professor disse no vídeo.

Como resolver?

Comment: coloque as tags normais, pra gente fazer uma leitura mais fluida.

Comment: Seu eclipse deve estar forçando a compilação em 1.5 faça isso :
`properties > java compiler > compiler complience level > 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

A tag `<source>1.8</source>` não está no local correto.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>smochin</groupId>
<artifactId>InstagramAPI</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1.v20150714</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Veja, está em `properties/source` e a sua configuração está em `build/plugins/plugin/configuration/source`.

Vale pra **target** também.